# Changing multi_array_ref data block after instantiation

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, boost

I have been experimenting with boost multi_array_refs because of their ability to map a 2D (In my case) array view of the world onto arbitrary blocks of contiguous memory. With a multi_array_ref, a pointer to the contiguous memory is specified to the constructor. That works fine, but in my ultimate application, what I would really like to do is take a pre-existing multi_array_ref object, and point it to new buffers that are allocated later, on the fly. It seems like this should be possible, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Here's some skeleton code that I hope demonstrates the type of thing I'm attempting to do, although it obviously won't work as written.

```
const int XSIZE = 10;
const int YSIZE = 5;

typedef boost::multi_array_ref<int, 2> ARRAY_2D_REF;

class Test2D {
public: 
   Test2D(const int sizeX, const int sizeY);
   ~Test2D();

   // I want to point this multi_array_ref to a buffer that gets
   // allocated in the constructor.
   ARRAY_2D_REF data;

private:
   int  xSize;
   int  ySize;
   int  *n;
};

// can't construct 'data' using ':' syntax here, because, the 'n'
// buffer has not been allocated yet so 'n' doesn't contain a valid
// address. This compiles okay, but segfaults if you try to use 'data'
// because 'n' contains garabge at this point.
Test2D::Test2D(const int sizeX, const int sizeY) : data(n, boost::extents[sizeX][sizeY])  // <<-- fail
{
   xSize = sizeX;
   ySize = sizeY;

   // In the actual application, n will be populated by data arriving
   // on TCP stream. The header on those mesasges contain total
   // contiguous buffer size and X,Y dimensions, followed by the data.
   n = (int*)malloc(xSize * ySize * sizeof(int));

   // I want to set the multi_array_ref origin and define extents right
   // here. The thought was to set the origin to 'n', and then
   // resize(), but how?  Of course I can't actually construct it here
   // as shown.  Seems like there should be a simple way to set
   // (change) the origin pointer. There probably is in fact. But I
   // can't seem to figure it out.
   data(n, boost::extents[xSize][ySize]);
}
```

Comment: To answer the title question strictly: You cannot re-initialize a `multi_array_ref` (full stop). If you want that behaviour, use indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Initializers in the initializer list are evaluated in order of declaration of class members (members after base-classes).

So, you fix it all by moving the `data` member declaration *after* the other members.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

static const int XSIZE = 10;
static const int YSIZE = 5;

typedef boost::multi_array_ref<int, 2> ARRAY_2D_REF;

class Test2D {
  public: 
    Test2D(const int sizeX, const int sizeY)
      : xSize(sizeX),
        ySize(sizeY),
        n (new int[xSize*ySize]),
        data(n, boost::extents[xSize][ySize])
    { }

    ~Test2D() {
        delete n;
    }

    Test2D(Test2D const&) = delete; // Rule Of Three!

  private:
    int  xSize;
    int  ySize;
    int  *n;
  public:
    ARRAY_2D_REF data;
};

int main() {
    Test2D wrapped(XSIZE, YSIZE);
}
```

Note *also* that

- there is no place for malloc in C++
- you should guard the type against copying, because otherwise you will do double-`delete` of the data buffer.

### Other Thoughts

It really doesn't make **any** sense to be allocating the buffer from inside the constructor (body, or initializer-list regardless), if your comment says:

// In the actual application, n will be populated by data arriving
   // on TCP stream. The header on those mesasges contain total
   // contiguous buffer size and X,Y dimensions, followed by the data.

The constructor doesn't have the dependencies necessary to do the allocation, nor SHOULD it. There are two options:

- if the buffer is always owned by the `Test2D` instance (and the data is going to be copied from the IO buffer(s)), then *just use `multi_array`, not `multi_array_ref`*. It does the allocations, safely, for you.
- otherwise, pass in the buffer:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <memory>

static const int XSIZE = 10;
static const int YSIZE = 5;
static const int HEADER_SIZE = 16;

typedef boost::const_multi_array_ref<int, 2> ArrayCRef;

class Test2D {
  public: 
    Test2D(int const* raw, int sizeX, int sizeY) : data(raw, boost::extents[sizeX][sizeY])
    { }

    ArrayCRef::size_type xSize() const { return data.shape()[0]; }
    ArrayCRef::size_type ySize() const { return data.shape()[1]; }
  public:
    ArrayCRef data;
};

int main() {
    auto io_buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(XSIZE*YSIZE*sizeof(int)+HEADER_SIZE);

    // TODO parse XSIZE/YSIZE from io_buf
    auto raw = reinterpret_cast<int const*>(io_buf.get() + HEADER_SIZE);

    Test2D wrapped(raw, XSIZE, YSIZE);
}
```